# How to relay mail via Google account using Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix

I want to non local emails to be relayed via my personal Google account and local to delivered to local user.
My configuration is:
/etc/postfix/transport

```
*            smtp:[smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

and /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
[root@media postfix]# cat main.cf
# This file contains only the parameters changed from a default install
# see /etc/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, fuller version of this file.
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:

```
[smtp.google.com]:587    myuser@gmail.com:mypass
```

And after I run:

```
# postmap transport && postmap sasl_passwd
systemctl restart postfix.service
```

So now my server try to connect to gmail MX (without success but not deliver email localy

Logs from journalctl:

```
    Jul 06 18:38:01 media postfix/pickup[31431]: 30714960F8: uid=0 from=<root>
    Jul 06 18:38:01 media postfix/cleanup[31641]: 30714960F8: message- id=<20130706163801.30714960F8@media.localdomain>
    Jul 06 18:38:01 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: 30714960F8: from=<root@media.localdomain>, size=436, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jul 06 18:38:01 media postfix/smtp[31643]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:4008:c01::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
   Jul 06 18:38:01 media postfix/smtp[31643]: 30714960F8: to=<mackowiakp23@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.108]:587, delay=0.7, delays=0.03/0.04/0.55/0.07, ...M command))
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/cleanup[31641]: 0B85D960F9: message-id=<20130706163802.0B85D960F9@media.localdomain>
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: 0B85D960F9: from=<>, size=2555, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/bounce[31646]: 30714960F8: sender non-delivery notification: 0B85D960F9
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: 30714960F8: removed
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/smtp[31643]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:4008:c01::6d]:587: Network is unreachable
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/smtp[31643]: 0B85D960F9: to=<root@media.localdomain>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.109]:587, delay=0.59, delays=0.02/0.01/0.51/0.06,...M command))
    Jul 06 18:38:02 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: 0B85D960F9: removed
    Jul 06 18:38:40 media auth[31778]: pam_tcb(dovecot:auth): Authentication passed for media from (uid=0)
    Jul 06 18:38:40 media dovecot[1442]: pop3-login: Login: user=<media>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.2, lip=192.168.0.7, mpid=31779, secured, session=<VZaXcdrgpADAqAAC>
    Jul 06 18:38:40 media dovecot[1442]: pop3(media): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
    Jul 06 18:38:58 media postfix/pickup[31431]: CD15D960F8: uid=0 from=<root>
    Jul 06 18:38:58 media postfix/cleanup[31641]: CD15D960F8: message-id=<20130706163858.CD15D960F8@media.localdomain>
    Jul 06 18:38:58 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: CD15D960F8: from=<root@media.localdomain>, size=430, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jul 06 18:38:59 media postfix/smtp[31643]: CD15D960F8: to=<mackowiakp@op.pl>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.108]:587, delay=0.63, delays=0.02/0/0.54/0.06, dsn=5.5....M command))
    Jul 06 18:38:59 media postfix/cleanup[31641]: BAB0E960F9: message-id=<20130706163859.BAB0E960F9@media.localdomain>
    Jul 06 18:38:59 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: BAB0E960F9: from=<>, size=2541, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Jul 06 18:38:59 media postfix/bounce[31646]: CD15D960F8: sender non-delivery notification: BAB0E960F9
    Jul 06 18:38:59 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: CD15D960F8: removed
Jul 06 18:39:00 media postfix/smtp[31643]: BAB0E960F9: to=<root@media.localdomain>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.109]:587, delay=0.66, delays=0.02/0.01/0.56/0.07,...M command))
    Jul 06 18:39:00 media postfix/qmgr[31432]: BAB0E960F9: removed
```

Any help to make it working?

Comment: Is that asterisk really in your /etc/postfix/transport, or is it just something that got added inadvertantly to your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable `TLS` in Postfix's SMTP client, since Google requires it. This is indicated by them in the message `Must issue a STARTTLS command`.

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, you want something like this:

`smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy`

and then in `/etc/postfix/tls_policy`:

`[smtp.gmail.com]:587 encrypt`

The left hand side in `tls_policy` must appear exactly the same as your relayhost entry in `main.cf`.

Remember to run `postmap` on `/etc/postfix/tls_policy` after creating or changing it as required.

You can find more details in Postfix's TLS documentation.

Refer these links

http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/postfix-gmail-and-you/

http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls

Answer (score 2):

This is the procedure I use for this:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix.
```

If it asks what sort of mail server you are installed, choose no configuration (the first option)

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and paste this in

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
# listen on localhost only
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name

biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

#Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Save the file, Now we create the file with the username and password in

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

and paste in the following making the required replacements

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user.name@gmail.com:password
```

Save it, and at the command prompt

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Then

```
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

Finally,

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Note that once you’ve successfully tested the email system, you can remove / obfuscate the password in sasl_passwd.

Test it with you application. If you have trouble, check /var/log/mail.log
You can apt-get install mail-utils to have it install a mail program. you can then test with

```
echo “this is a test” | mailx -s “This is the subject” destination@example.com
```

Finally

Run

```
newaliases
```

to make an /etc/aliases.db file. If you don’t it will log a lot of errors about it to /var/log/mail.err
If you get SASL errors (postfix)
Check the hostname is in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname
If postfix complains about not being able to relay for a given host / ip address (postfix)
Add this to /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8
```

This will allow anyone with a 10.0.0.0 address to connect, obviously you should bolt this down as much as possible, either by restricting the network, and / or using any firewall or security policy available to you

Comment: OK. THX. But what You use to create/obtain /etc/ssl/certs/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem certificate?

Comment: My mistake, You shouldn't need that line. I've edited the post above to reflect this

Comment: I got info: <test.user@domain.com>: host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.109] said: 530-5.5.1
    Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
    http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 fc7sm2465531bkc.3
    - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command) - so in such configuration MAIL FROM must be included in relay definition. How can I do it?

Comment: Oh s*&^*t ! In /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd was [smtp.google.com]:587 instead [smtp.gmail.com]:587. Sometimes is terribly difficult to find out such simple error. THX! WORKS!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure to check first Google's authentication method:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

If the page is not available for your account, then the the domain administrator disabled this settings for all users (default).

When you whitelist your IP/range in Relay SMTP in google admin, you can send emails with this settings

```
relayhost = [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_loglevel=1
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login, plain
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

However, when `Allow less secure apps: OFF` I was always getting these messages:

```
(SASL authentication failed; server smtp-relay.gmail.com[173.194.204.28] said: 534-5.7.14
... Please log in via your web browser and?534-5.7.14 then try again.?534-5.7.14
Learn more at?534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g133sm1077601qkb.1 - gsmtp)
```

but messages were still delivered (which is a bit strange), although it took a bit longer to get message to its recipient.